# Pandas installed with pip3 now taking much longer

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I changed my requirements.txt to include a new Pandas version (==0.22.0).  This is running in an Ubuntu Docker container.  Before, when building the container, Pandas would install fairly quickly.  Now, it takes several minutes, and several " Running setup.py install for pandas: still running..." messages appear before it completes.

My theory is that Pandas is now compiling on my system as part of the install, whereas before it was not.  Is there any way I can get the "faster" Pandas back, other than reverting to the old version number?

Comment: Describe step by step what you're doing and what commands are running in both cases and their output. See [ask] amd [mcve].

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - pip install pandas is the entirety of it.  It was fast one day, slow the next (after I decided to pip install a newer version).  I install it frequently and it wasn't just a one time issue.

Comment: `pip install pandas` has nothing to do with a `requirements.txt` because it installs pandas directly and also not a specific version but the default one. Which should be 0.23.0.  If there is compiling involved then either pandas itself or a dependency isn't available precompiled as wheel file.

Comment: @BlackJack pip install -r requirements.txt ?  And as I implied in my question (actually outright stated), the requirements.txt now includes the new version explicitly (==0.22.0)

Comment: When asked for actual steps/an MCV you wrote `pip install pandas` and not `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Maybe using the `--log` argument of `pip` helps in determining the cause/difference of installing the different pandas versions.

Comment: What version of Python? Can I guess it's Python 3.4?